# How to specify core_pattern in systemd service file?

Tags: service, linux-kernel, crash, systemd, coredump

How can I specify core pattern for a particular service in systemd without affecting core patterns for other services?

Comment: Does Linux support per-process or per-cgroup core patterns? I’m only aware of the global `/proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern` file.